# NodeJS не открывает файл .js

Tags: node.js

При подгрузке файла .js выдает ошибку [image: Ошибка]

Содержимое файла:

```
console.log("Success!");
```

Не понятны причины :/ Делаю все по руководству

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы делаете это, **уже** запустив `node`. В этот момент вы уже находитесь в JavaScript [REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) (в трейсе ошибки, видите?) и можете вводить непосредственный код на JavaScript. Введите вместо `node m.js` **содержимое файла** (`console.log("Success!")`) и оно успешно выполнится.

`node m.js` это команда для оболочки ОС на запуск `node` с аргументом `m.js`, в котором `node` узнает путь к файлу и выполнит его.

- Найдите папку, содержащую `m.js` в Проводнике
- Удерживая <kbd>Shift</kbd>, щёлкните по папке *правой кнопкой мыши*
- Выберите *"Открыть окно команд"*: откроется окно с `cmd.exe` в нужной папке
- Во всплывшем окне введите `node m.js` и нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Запустить этот файл можно даже из запущенного в этой же папке `node`! Вот так:

```
require("./m.js")
```